# sql multiple count

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables, where the first one's primary key, is the foreign key in the other 2.

I want to extract one field from the first table, and then a count from the other 2, all joined using the pk and fk.  This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT MBDDX_STUDY.STUDY_NAME, COUNT(MBDDX_EXPERIMENT.STUDY_ID) AS NUMBER_OF_EXPERIMENTS
FROM MBDDX_STUDY
INNER JOIN MBDDX_EXPERIMENT
ON MBDDX_STUDY.ID=MBDDX_EXPERIMENT.STUDY_ID 
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.GROUP_NO) AS NUMBER_OF_GROUPS 
FROM MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP) 
ON MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.STUDY_ID = MBDDX_STUDY.ID
group by MBDDX_STUDY.STUDY_NAME, MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.STUDY_ID
```

But, i get an error saying that the MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.STUDY_ID , in the penultimate line is an invalid indentifier.  It is a correct table.

Any advise please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery syntax doesn't seem to make any sense to me. You've made a query that counts *all* rows of MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP, independently of the STUDY_ID, and then tries to join it into the table with a join condition that doesn't refer to anything in the subquery's results (and can't, without an alias).

Why not use a simple join? Assuming `MBDDX_EXPERIMENT` also has a primary key `ID`, you can do it with a COUNT-DISTINCT:

```
SELECT
    MBDDX_STUDY.ID, MBDDX_STUDY.STUDY_NAME,
    COUNT(DISTINCT MBDDX_EXPERIMENT.ID) AS NUMBER_OF_EXPERIMENTS
    COUNT(DISTINCT MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.GROUP_NO) AS NUMBER_OF_GROUPS
FROM
    MBDDX_STUDY
    INNER JOIN MBDDX_EXPERIMENT ON MBDDX_EXPERIMENT.STUDY_ID=MBDDX_STUDY.ID
    INNER JOIN MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP ON MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.STUDY_ID=MBDDX_STUDY.ID
GROUP BY
    MBDDX_STUDY.ID, MBDDX_STUDY.STUDY_NAME
```

(MBDDX_STUDY.STUDY_NAME technically shouldn't be necessary to include in the GROUP BY expression according to ANSI SQL as it has a functional dependency on STUDY_ID. However it is necessary on Oracle, which can't spot the dependency.)

Comment: Thank you Bob.  This works perfectly.  I guess I was over complicating things.  When I use the select statements, does each from statement correspond to the select statement in order?  Ie, select 1 = from 1, select 2 = from 2, etc?  Do they need to be in that order?  Much like programming function parameters?

Comment: No: the order of the select terms can be anything you like, so arrange them however's most readable.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error because that column is not in your `SELECT`, so it can't `GROUP BY` a field it doesn't have.

Comment: I've taken that part out now, but I still get the same answer?

Comment: That's because you aren't selecting that field in your JOIN either.  You are selecting a COUNT `(SELECT COUNT(MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.GROUP_NO) AS NUMBER_OF_GROUPS 
FROM MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP)` but nowhere do you have that field in your statement.  However you are using it as a `JOIN` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to group by this field (`MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.STUDY_ID`). It should be just `group by MBDDX_STUDY.STUDY_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct,You need a record from first table and have the count of related records in the other two tables.Here is the answer

[SQL:Getting count from many tables for a user record in USER table.Whats the best approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835678/sqlgetting-count-from-many-tables-for-a-user-record-in-user-table-whats-the-best)

Comment: Okay, will give that a go.  Just logging off now, so will try Monday.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to alias the second subquery and need to include something to join on.

It also looks like you aren't using the `count` you have in the subquery as well.
Try this out:

```
SELECT MBDDX_STUDY.STUDY_NAME
, COUNT(MBDDX_EXPERIMENT.STUDY_ID) AS NUMBER_OF_EXPERIMENTS 
FROM MBDDX_STUDY 
INNER JOIN MBDDX_EXPERIMENT 
ON MBDDX_STUDY.ID=MBDDX_EXPERIMENT.STUDY_ID 
INNER JOIN (SELECT STUDY_ID, COUNT(MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.GROUP_NO) AS NUMBER_OF_GROUPS 
            FROM MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP GROUP BY MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.STUDY_ID) xx 
ON xx.STUDY_ID = MBDDX_STUDY.ID 
GROUP BY MBDDX_STUDY.STUDY_NAME, xx.STUDY_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you really want to do, you want `OUTER JOIN`s.

```
WITH   number_of_experiments
AS     ( SELECT study_id
              , count ( * ) CNT
           FROM MBDDX_EXPERIMENT
          group by study_id )
     , number_of_groups
as     ( select study_id
              , count ( * ) CNT
           FROM mbddx_treatment_group
          group by study_id )
select study_name
     , coalesce(noex.cnt,0)
     , coalesce(notr.cnt,0)
  from mbddx_study
 outer join number_of_experiments
as     noex
 using ( study_id )
 outer join number_of_groups
as     nogr
 using ( study_id )
```