# Oracle SQL help

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

I posted on Friday ([sql multiple count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997919/sql-multiple-count)) and had a few responses.

Having tried to implement them today, I keep getting the same error.

My SQL code now is:

```
SELECT MBDDX_STUDY.STUDY_NAME,
       COUNT(MBDDX_EXPERIMENT.STUDY_ID)
AS     NUMBER_OF_EXPERIMENTS
FROM MBDDX_STUDY
INNER JOIN MBDDX_EXPERIMENT
       ON MBDDX_STUDY.ID = MBDDX_EXPERIMENT.STUDY_ID
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.GROUP_NO)
            FROM MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP)
       ON MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.STUDY_ID = MBDDX_STUDY.ID
GROUP BY MBDDX_STUDY.STUDY_NAME
```

I keep getting the error:

> ORA-00904: "MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP"."STUDY_ID": invalid identifier

Is it because it is outside of the inner join bracket, i.e. out of scope?  I am very new to SQL and cannot understand why it wont work.  I can get it working using select subqueries (without joins) but I want to also be able to work with joins.

If it matters any I am using Toad for Oracle.

Thanks.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything new in this compared to your last question. Please edit/comment on your previous question rather than posting anew if it is essentially the same question. See my answer there for an approach that does not require subqueries at all.

Comment: Thanks Bob.   I have used your solution in the other thread and it works perfectly and is a lot cleaner than what I was trying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql multiple count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997919/sql-multiple-count)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you join with a query. Give a name to that query, and refer to it that way:

```
SELECT MBDDX_STUDY.STUDY_NAME
     , COUNT ( MBDDX_EXPERIMENT.STUDY_ID )
AS     NUMBER_OF_EXPERIMENTS
  FROM MBDDX_STUDY
 INNER JOIN MBDDX_EXPERIMENT
    ON MBDDX_STUDY.ID = MBDDX_EXPERIMENT.STUDY_ID
 inner JOIN ( SELECT study_id, COUNT ( MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.GROUP_NO )
            FROM MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP  group by study_id ) AS my_query
    ON my_query.STUDY_ID = MBDDX_STUDY.ID
 GROUP BY MBDDX_STUDY.STUDY_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have just tried your suggestion and it now says: ORA-00905: missing keyword, This is caused by the AS my_query?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my answer. You can check the edition log or paste it again.

Comment: It works if I drop the AS keyword.  Well, I say it works.  It doesn't show me the new column.  I guess that is a problem with my logic?

Comment: If you want something to be reported, you must state it in the most outer SELECT statement. Inner SELECTs create temporary views that are used for joining.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for that.  Within the outer select, I have tried writing my_query.group_no  my_query.study_id , etc and nothing seems to work?  Apologies for the many questions and thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, a subquery must have an alias.  Change:

```
inner JOIN ( SELECT COUNT ( MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.GROUP_NO )
    FROM MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP )
ON MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.STUDY_ID = MBDDX_STUDY.ID
```

to

```
inner JOIN ( SELECT COUNT ( MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.GROUP_NO )
    FROM MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP ) as CountAlias
ON MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.STUDY_ID = MBDDX_STUDY.ID
```

The second thing is that you have to include all columns you plan to use.  Right now, the subquery just selects a count, but the `ON` clause references `STUDY_ID`.  You can fix that by including `STUDY_ID` in the subquery select list, like:

```
inner JOIN ( 
    SELECT  STUDY_ID
    ,       COUNT(MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.GROUP_NO) as GroupCount
    FROM MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP) as CountAlias
ON MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.STUDY_ID = MBDDX_STUDY.ID
```

Now after that, you might hit other issues, but I'm hoping this will get you started.

Comment: I like that structured way of forming your answer. +1 for that.

Comment: SELECT MBDDX_STUDY.STUDY_NAME 
     , COUNT ( MBDDX_EXPERIMENT.STUDY_ID ) 
AS     NUMBER_OF_EXPERIMENTS 
  FROM MBDDX_STUDY 
 INNER JOIN MBDDX_EXPERIMENT 
    ON MBDDX_STUDY.ID = MBDDX_EXPERIMENT.STUDY_ID 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT study_id, COUNT ( MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP.GROUP_NO ) AS Number_of_groups
            FROM MBDDX_TREATMENT_GROUP group by study_id ) my_query
    ON my_query.STUDY_ID = MBDDX_STUDY.ID 
 GROUP BY MBDDX_STUDY.STUDY_NAME  But, the new column does not show in the table?  Is that a problem with the join?  Thanks

Comment: @Benoit: Thanks!  @DarrenYoung: Try to add `myquery.Number_of_groups` to the select list, before the first `from`?

Comment: No, that's not doing anything?  Is my logic okay?